# Show a transposed grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there an option, or a reasonably simple way in code, to get ag-grid to show a transposed grid?

By that I mean transposing rows and columns; columns down the side, rows across the top; column and row styles transposed to match.

I'm using React, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't. I finished up doing it mostly by hand,

Comment: same from my side, I loop through the matrix, didn't like that way